# R caret: how to change constant parameter?

Tags: r

I'm using caret package in R for generating classification model.
One of algorithms I try to use is CART.

As I know, there are two methods for using CART algorithm.
One is rpart and the other is rpart2.
The difference between them is tuning parameter.
rpart's tuning parameter is cp, and rpart2's is maxdepth.

However, I want to find the optimal combination of those two parameters.
So I tried like below.

```
tc <- trainControl(method="cv", number=5, summaryFunction=twoClassSummary, classProbs=TRUE)
rpart.grid <- expand.grid(cp=seq(0.01, 0.1, 0.01), maxdepth=seq(5, 30, 5))
train.rpart <- train(target~., data=data, method="rpart", trControl=tc, metric="ROC", tuneGrid=rpart.grid)
```

But it doesn't work, and print "The tuning parameter grid should have columns cp."
And I guess this is because the rpart method only allows to change cp.

Is there any way to change those two parameters?